# How can this code be optimized?

Tags: c#, reflection, datatable

I have a method which in essence converts a datatable to a list of objects which I call 'Bags'.  This code is called many times per session, with many sessions concurrently running and with sometimes thousands of rows.  Because of this I need it to be as quick as possible.  I have an xml file which contains the DataColumn to Property mappings. The main method to optimize is `ConvertRowToBag` - the type parameter passed in is a type which derives from `BagBase`.

It's a long bit of code, but any tips would be much appreciated.

```
public class BagBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary of properties and names
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propertyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Table of column/property mappings
    /// </summary>
    private static DataTable mappings = new DataTable("Mappings");

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the map exists
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columnName"></param>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool MappingExists(string columnName, Type type)
    {
        DataRow [] rows = BagBase.mappings.Select(String.Format("Type = '{0}' and ColumnName = '{1}'", type.Name, columnName));
        return (rows != null && rows.Length > 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the table to bags.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="table">The table.</param>
    /// <param name="outputType">Type of the output.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected static List<BagBase> ConvertTableToBags(DataTable table, Type outputType)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation(String.Format("ConvertTableToBags : table={0} Type={1}", table.TableName, outputType.Name));

        // Create an empty list
        List<BagBase> result = new List<BagBase>();

        // Iterate through the rows
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            // Add to the list
            result.Add(ConvertRowToBag(outputType, row));
        }

        Trace.TraceInformation("ConvertTableToBags Finished.");

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the row to bag.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="outputType">Type of the output.</param>
    /// <param name="row">The row.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected static BagBase ConvertRowToBag(Type outputType, DataRow row)
    {
        // Create an instance of the child class and store in the base
        BagBase bag = Activator.CreateInstance(outputType) as BagBase;

        // Iterate through the columns
        foreach (DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            // If this column has been mapped
            if (BagBase.MappingExists(column.ColumnName, outputType))
            {
                PropertyInfo property;

                string columnProperty = String.Format("{0}={1}", column.ColumnName, outputType.Name);

                // Get the property as defined in the map
                if (!propertyDictionary.ContainsKey(columnProperty))
                {
                    // Get the property
                    property = outputType.GetProperty(BagBase.GetColumnMapping(column.ColumnName, outputType));

                    // Add the property to the dictionary
                    propertyDictionary.Add(columnProperty, property);
                }
                else
                {
                    property = propertyDictionary[columnProperty];
                }

                if (property != null)
                {
                    if (!row.IsNull(column))
                    {
                        // Set the value to the in the table
                        if (property.PropertyType.BaseType != null && property.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                        {
                            if (column.DataType != typeof(String))
                            {
                                property.SetValue(bag, Enum.ToObject(property.PropertyType, row[column]), null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                property.SetValue(bag, Enum.ToObject(property.PropertyType, Convert.ToChar(row[column])), null);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                        {
                            property.SetValue(bag, (DateTime?)row[column], null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            property.SetValue(bag, Convert.ChangeType(row[column], property.PropertyType), null);
                        }
                    }
                    else // No nulls
                    {
                        if (column.DataType == typeof(String))
                        {
                            property.SetValue(bag, String.Empty, null);
                        }
                    }

                    // Generate the unique class.property name
                    string propertyKey = String.Format("{0}.{1}", outputType.Name, property.Name);
                    if (!columnCaptions.ContainsKey(propertyKey))
                    {
                        // Add to the caption map
                        columnCaptions.Add(propertyKey, column.Caption);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If this column isn't mapped, add it to Other information
                if (bag.OtherInformation == null)
                {
                    bag.OtherInformation = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                }

                bag.OtherInformation.Add(column.ColumnName, !row.IsNull(column) ? row[column].ToString() : String.Empty);
            }
        }

        return bag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Profiling should indeed reveal any bottlenecks or else posting it on  refactormycode.com can give you maybe more insights.

Comment: Thanks for the link - its the first time I've heard of that site.

Comment: refactormycode is down for maintenance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a profiler. There's no way for us to know what actually takes the most time in your code.

There's just really no use trying to optimize line-by-line and many people seem to not know this. Computers are always waiting for a resource, sometimes it's CPU or disk IO, and often it's the user. To make any piece of code faster, find the bottlenecks using a profiler and work on making that code faster.

Comment: You can earn so much reputation on this site just by saying "use a profiler" for this type of question, because it's *always* the right answer. Have another 10 points.

Comment: +1 "use a profiler" is a correct, but not directly helpful answer.

Comment: +1, I think it's helpful. A lot of people obviously don't realize it.

Comment: Having spent the better part of the last two weeks looking for bottlenecks in our core product at work, I can say with certainty that "Use a profiler" is absolutely entirely the best answer to this type of question. I've refactored and optimized about 20 odd pieces of code and in only 1 of those I was spot on with my own intuition before I ran the profiler, the rest was just "Whoah, it spends time *there*?"

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen - Do you mind if I ask which profiler you used?

Comment: @PhilipW - My currently preferred profiler is Red Gate Ants. It's really easy to use and gives you line-level performance information.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the general advise of "use a profiler", there is probably not one bottleneck but either a series of slow calls or the very structure of the procedure is creating unnecessary iterations.  At a glance:

- The Select against a datatable is generally not very performant.
- Reflection carries with it a lot of overhead, it looks like you are dependent on it but if you could limit its scope you will probably get better overall performance.

Comment: It sounds like you actually read the code!  Thanks for the suggestions... :)